# ClientContext error while embedding a Silverlight control on ASP page

Tags: client-object-model, asp.net, silverlight, spcontext

I build a visual web part in asp.net and I'm trying to embed a xap over it so that users who don't have Silverlight installed would see the asp content:

> `<object id="SilverlightPlugin1" width="300" height="400"
>       data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
>       type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
>       <param name="source" value="/content/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
>       />`

It all seems to work except the silverlight app doesn't seem to like that way of being embedded - the Chrome console gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: webFullUrl   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext..ctor(String webFullUrl)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext..ctor(String webFullUrl)
>      at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.GetItemFromSharePointList()
>      at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage..ctor()
>      at SilverlightApplication1.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
>      at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
>      at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)

I suspect it has something to do with me using 
`ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);`
in the silverlight code. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, had to provide the context in the init params of my object tag.

> `<object id="SilverlightPlugin1" width="400" height="300"
>       data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
>       type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
>       <param name="source" value="/content/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
>       <param name="initParams" value="MS.SP.url=<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Url %>"`